# BCS association of external entity to self

Tags: sharepoint, associations, bcs

I have a BCS model in SharePoint. This model has a single entity that should have multiple child entities of the same kind. I tried to associate the entity to self but the association does not appear on the entities' forms in the list. I expect to have a user experience that is  similar to having a lookup field in a generic list that looks up to the same list.

How can I implement this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I found so far is to create 2 different entities, create an association between them and make these two entities return data from the same source (in my case a .Net class).